# Display file and number from electron-log

Tags: javascript, logging, electron

I would like to display the file and line number where I call an electron-log function from in the developer tools console. Currently it just displays `console.js:77` to the right of each log, which is where electron-log internally logs to the developer tools console from.

I could just call the two functions like I have below to determine where the log is coming from and continue to log to file at the same time, but a single line solution would be preferable. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
console.log(message)
log.info(message)
```